# Can you open a terminal while Ubuntu is installing?

Tags: installation

Can you open a terminal while Ubuntu is installing?   I remember in the old days when I could install Linux and hit like F-12 or something and see the installation log and in the really old days of Debian I could hit F1, F2, etc and get different terminals while the install was occurring.  Is this possible in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember you can click the arrow in the down left hand corner, next to "Installing system".

You can see it here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was good enough to at least give me some minimal information.  I appreciate it.